# Ruby on Rails. Unicode routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, routes

Is it possible to set a Unicode string as a segment of a path in Rails?

I try the following:

```
  
# app/controllers/magazines_controller.rb

class MagazinesController < ApplicationController
  def index                                     
  end                                                                           
end
```

```
  
# encoding: utf-8
# config/routes.rb

PublishingHouse::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :magazines,
    :only => :index,
    :path => :журналы # a Unicode string is set as a segment of the path
end
```

```
$ rake routes
magazines GET /журналы(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"magazines"}
```

But when I go to the path I get the Routing error:

```
$ w3m http://localhost:3000/журналы
...

Routing Error

No route matches "/%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B"
```

Here's the server log:

```
$ rails s thin
...

Started GET "/%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-09-26 13:35:00 +0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B"):

Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.2ms)
```

Thanks.

Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.6;

Ruby 1.9.2;

Ruby on Rails 3.0.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Intereting, I think Rails need a patch for this. I shall speak with someone from core about it later. In the meantime, the following should work:

```
PublishingHouse::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :magazines,
    :only => :index,
    :path => Rack::Utils.escape('журналы') # a Unicode string is set as a segment of the path
end
```

Comment: It's discussed as a Rails issue here:             https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3470