# Rails routing: Wildcard and german umlauts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, wildcard

I'm just developing a WebDAV interface for a Rails App. Therefor I'm routing all webdav.example.com/path/to/folder paths to a webdav controller:

```
scope controller: 'webdav', constraints: {subdomain: 'webdav'} do
  get '*path', action: 'show'
  # some more webdav specific routes...
end
```

Everything works fine, but for a folder called 'Verträge' the native Windows client now requests webdav.example.com/Vertr%E4ge which unfortunately breaks the rails routing process raising an ActionController::BadRequest...

After some research I figured out that i.e. Gems like HighVoltage have the same problem.

Does anybody has an idea to solve this? Regardless of telling Windows to send a real 'ä' or fixing it at rails side...

UPDATE:

%E4 belongs to ISO-8859-1 (ISO Latin 1) Character Encoding, but Rails routing works with UTF-8.

So GET webdav.example.com/Vertr%C3%A4ge works perfectly fine.

How do I get either Windows to UTF8 encode the urls or Rails to recognize and convert the urls properly before dispatching the request?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797389/ruby-on-rails-unicode-routes

Comment: I've already found this too. There's a problem matching the path which leads to a 404. In my case ActionController::BadRequest is beeing raised --> 400.

Answer (score 1):

Currently ended up patching ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher this way: https://gist.github.com/sdhull/9240273

Other solutions / discussions are welcome :)